# How does this C++ structure get transferred from the function to the “your” member

Tags: c++

```
struct movies_t {
    string title;
    int year;
} mine, yours;

void printmovie (movies_t movie);

int main ()
{
    string mystr;

    mine.title = "2001 A Space Odyssey";
    mine.year = 1968;

    cout << "Enter title: ";
    getline (cin,yours.title);
    cout << "Enter year: ";
    getline (cin,mystr);
    stringstream(mystr) >> yours.year;

    cout << "My favorite movie is:\n ";
    printmovie (mine);
    cout << "And yours is:\n ";
    printmovie (yours);
    return 0;
}

void printmovie (movies_t movie)
{
    cout << movie.title;
    cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n
```

I’m trying to understand how the function member “movie” is able to carry the data into the main program if a different member is being used

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Unrelated: `movies_t` should be `movie_t`.

Comment: Since the year is a number, you should enter it as so:  `std::cin >> yours.year;`.

Comment: Names ending with `_t` are reserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I’m trying to understand how the function member “movie” is able to
>   carry the data into the main program if a different member is being
>   used

```
printmovie (yours);

void printmovie (movies_t movie)
//               ^^^^^^^^
//               copy of structure
```

What happens is that you're passing a copy of `yours` to the function `printmovie()` and you're calling this copy `movie`

Comment: Oh dammit I must have had a stroke. I didn’t notice the function call at the end lmao. Thank you